# Segue from table cells not doing anything

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have a fairly simple question. Basically, I am creating a menu using a table view, and I would like each row be a tappable button that takes the user to the corresponding view controller.

I have implemented everything as it should be, but nothing happens when the cells are tapped.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath == 0 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Career", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath == 1 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Routine", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath == 2 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Skills", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath == 3 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Projects", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath == 4 {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("Interests", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I have the correct segue identifiers set up, so it should work fine, but there must be an issue somewhere.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does "nothing happens" mean that `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called, or that it _is_ called and no segue is performed?  In either case I think you want to be comparing against `indexPath.row` as opposed to just `indexPath`.

Comment: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` was being called, but you are correct, I should have been checking `indexPath.row`. Thanks a lot! I should have spotted that.